# Cannot edit entries after Redactor 2.0.1 upgrade

Tags: redactor

I upgraded to Redactor 2.0.1 on Craft Pro 3.0.6, and now I'm getting this error anytime I try to edit an entry that uses Redactor.

InvalidConfigException('Redactor plugin not found: '.$plugin);

I have disabled and re-enabled the plugin to no avail.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'm unsure how to make it happy, and I haven't found anything in my Google/StackExchange searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an unfair advantage since I got to look at your logs from your support ticket, but here's the error from the logs:

> [error][yii\base\InvalidConfigException] yii\base\InvalidConfigException: Redactor plugin not found: source

If you look at the [Changelog for Redactor 2.0.0](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor/blob/v2/CHANGELOG.md#removed), you'll see the "Source" plugin is no longer needed.

The upgrade from Redactor 1.x to 2.0 should have tried to clean up any `craft/config/redactor/*.json` config files you might have removing references to the "Source" plugin, but something might have went wrong (permission errors are the most common cause of that).

Regardless, if you update those Redactor config files, the error should go away.